# Formik in tabs React

Tags: reactjs, tabs, formik

Want to use formik with tabs but have alot of forms ,one way is adding all my form inside the formik with the tabs but the code will not be very effiecient ,any example of tabs and components with formik to get all values any examples or liks will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Just have to add values as props and handleChnage , for everything to work and errors as useFormikContext()
```

LOGINCOMPONENT

```
const LoginDetails = props => {
    let captureForm = useFormikContext();

    return (
        <div>
            
                    <Box mt={2}>
                        <TextField
                            error={Boolean(
                                captureForm.touched.loginCode && captureForm.errors.loginCode
                            )}
                            helperText={
                                captureForm.touched.loginCode && captureForm.errors.loginCode
                            }
                            fullWidth
                            label="Login Code"
                            name="loginCode"
                            onChange={props.onChange}
                            value={props.values.loginCode}
                            variant="outlined"
                            onBlur={() => captureForm.setFieldTouched('loginCode', true)}
                        />
                    </Box>
                    <Box mt={2}>
                        <TextField
                            error={Boolean(
                                captureForm.touched.password && captureForm.errors.password
                            )}
                            helperText={
                                captureForm.touched.password && captureForm.errors.password
                            }
                            fullWidth
                            label="Password"
                            name="password"
                            type={'password'}
                            onChange={props.onChange}
                            value={props.values.password}
                            variant="outlined"
                            onBlur={() => captureForm.setFieldTouched('password', true)}
                        />
                    </Box>

        </div>
    );
};

export default LoginDetails;



//FORMIK
<Formik
                innerRef={formRef}
                enableReinitialize={true}
                initialValues={{
                    
                    //Login
                    loginCode: currentEntityData.loginCode || '',
                    password: currentEntityData.password || '',

                }}
                validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                    
                    
                    //Login
                    [props.entityType === 3 ? 'loginCode' : '']:
                        Yup.string().required('LoginCode is required.') || '',

                    [props.entityType === 3 ? 'password' : '']:
                        Yup.string().required('Password is required.') || '',

                    
                    verified: Yup.bool(),
                })}
                onSubmit={async (
                    values,
                    { resetForm, setErrors, setStatus, setSubmitting }
                ) => {
                    try {
                        //Call submitForm function then notification
                        submitForm(values).then(() => {
                            setMessageDisplay(true);
                            props.closeentityform();
                            props.refreshtable();
                        });
                    } catch (error) {
                        setStatus({ success: false });
                        setErrors({ submit: error.message });
                        setSubmitting(false);
                    }
                }}
            >
                {({
                    errors,
                    handleBlur,
                    handleChange,
                    handleSubmit,
                    isSubmitting,
                    setFieldTouched,
                    setFieldValue,
                    touched,
                    values,
                }) => (
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} {...props}>
                        <Card>
                            {/*Banking Dialogue */}
                            
                            <CardContent>
                                {/*Forms based in tabs */}
                                {/*Selective tabs based on type */}
                                <Tabs
                                    value={value}
                                    onChange={handleTabChange}
                                    variant="scrollable"
                                    textColor="primary"
                                    scrollButtons="auto"
                                >
                                    
                                
                                    {props.entitytype === 3 ? <Tab label="Login Details" /> : ''}
                                    {/*Login*/}
                                

                                </Tabs>

                                {value === 0 && (
                                    //Data
                                )}

                                
                                {/*///////////////////////Login Details//////////////////////////// */}
                                {props.entitytype === 1
                                    ? value === 3
                                    : value === 2 && (
                                            <>
                                                <Box mt={2}>
                                                    <LoginDetails
                                                        values={values}
                                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                                    />
                                                </Box>
                                            </>
                                      )}

                                {/*///////////////////////Member Details//////////////////////////// */}

                                {props.entitytype === 2
                                    ? value === 1 && (
                                            <>
                                                <MemberShip values={values} onChange={handleChange} />
                                            </>
                                      )
                                    : props.entitytype === 1
                                    ? value === 2 && (
                                            <>
                                                <MemberShip values={values} onChange={handleChange} />
                                            </>
                                      )
                                    : ''}

                                {/*/////////////////////////////////Staff //////////////////////////////*/}
                                {props.entitytype === 1
                                    ? value === 3
                                    : value === 3 && (
                                            <>
                                                <Box mt={2}>
                                                    <Grid container spacing={3}>
                                                        <Grid item xs={4}>
                                                            <Typography>User</Typography>
                                                            <Checkbox
                                                                name="userCheck"
                                                                color="primary"
                                                                checked={userCheck}
                                                                onChange={() => isUserSelected()}
                                                            ></Checkbox>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                        <Grid item xs={4}>
                                                            <Typography>Financial User</Typography>
                                                            <Checkbox
                                                                name="financialUserCheck"
                                                                color="primary"
                                                                checked={financialUserCheck}
                                                                onChange={() => isFinancialUserSelected()}
                                                            ></Checkbox>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                        <Grid item xs={4}>
                                                            <Typography>Admin</Typography>
                                                            <Checkbox
                                                                name="userCheck"
                                                                color="primary"
                                                                checked={adminCheck}
                                                                onChange={() => isAdminSelected()}
                                                            ></Checkbox>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                    <Box mt={2}></Box>
                                                    <TextField
                                                        fullWidth
                                                        label="Staff Number"
                                                        name="staff.staffId"
                                                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                                        value={values.staff.staffId}
                                                        variant="outlined"
                                                        error={Boolean(
                                                            getIn(touched, 'staff.staffId') &&
                                                                getIn(errors, 'staff.staffId')
                                                        )}
                                                        helperText={
                                                            getIn(touched, 'staff.staffId') &&
                                                            getIn(errors, 'staff.staffId')
                                                        }
                                                    />
                                                </Box>
                                                <Box mt={2}>
                                                    <TextField
                                                        fullWidth
                                                        label="Join Date"
                                                        type={'date'}
                                                        name="staff.joinDate"
                                                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                                        value={values.staff.joinDate}
                                                        variant="outlined"
                                                        error={Boolean(
                                                            getIn(touched, 'staff.joinDate') &&
                                                                getIn(errors, 'staff.joinDate')
                                                        )}
                                                        helperText={
                                                            getIn(touched, 'staff.joinDate') &&
                                                            getIn(errors, 'staff.joinDate')
                                                        }
                                                    />
                                                </Box>
                                                <Box mt={2}>
                                                    <TextField
                                                        fullWidth
                                                        label="Leave Date"
                                                        type="date"
                                                        name="staff.leaveDate"
                                                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                                        value={values.staff.leaveDate}
                                                        variant="outlined"
                                                        error={Boolean(
                                                            getIn(touched, 'staff.leaveDate') &&
                                                                getIn(errors, 'staff.leaveDate')
                                                        )}
                                                        helperText={
                                                            getIn(touched, 'staff.leaveDate') &&
                                                            getIn(errors, 'staff.leaveDate')
                                                        }
                                                    />
                                                </Box>
                                            </>
                                      )}

                                

                                <Box mt={3}>
                                    <Button
                                        variant="contained"
                                        color="secondary"
                                        type="submit"
                                        disabled={isSubmitting}
                                    >
                                        {props.id ? 'Save Changes' : 'Add User'}
                                    </Button>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <Button
                                        onClick={props.closeentityform}
                                        variant="contained"
                                        color="secondary"
                                        disabled={isSubmitting}
                                    >
                                        Cancel
                                    </Button>
                                </Box>
                            </CardContent>
                        </Card>
                    </form>
                )}
            </Formik>
```